# RDP Remote server very slow

Tags: server, 20.04, gnome, remote-desktop

I was wondering if there was a recommended way to speed up a remote desktop/server connection

I have installed the GNOME Ubuntu desktop GUI on my Ubuntu 20.04 server alongside XRDP
I am connecting to the server from Windows 10 using Remote Desktop Connection

Is a slow connection to a server to be expected or are there recommended ways to speed it up?

XRPD was installed using

```
sudo apt install xrdp
sudo systemctl status xrdp
sudo adduser xrdp ssl-cert
```

Ubuntu Gnome installed using

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop
```

I am currently using a wired connection offering 360mbps download and 30mbps upload.

Comment: we don't know what your network connection is like, and that could be some/all of the slowness

Comment: @Esther I have a 360mbps download speed and a 30mbps upload.

Comment: Wired or WiFi? Please [edit] your post to add new information, properly formatted. Information added via comments is hard for you to format, hard for us to read and ignored by future readers (who have better answers). Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our way to help you improve your question. All facts about your system and problem should go in the Question with [edit].  Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting .

Comment: @waltinator I have added the requested details to the question